# testcafe test occasionally hanging when run in semaphore

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

This is not about pinning down the hang as such, its more about wondering if there is a way to make testcafe decide the test must be a failure after a given period of time.

Our test works fine on local machines, but occasionally when run in CI using a docker image on semaphore one of the selectors causes it to hang. I am fine ivestigating why *that* is, but it would be good if I could tesll the test to give up after say 5 minutes (it should finish in under 3) and exit gracefully so we can have the stack trace and video - if we have to kill the test run we don;t get either, so we end up having to debug by the logging we emit from the test code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this functionality is not implemented in TestCafe. Please track the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6096 issue to check our progress.